# SQL Server 2008 How to create multiple tables for each record in a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains consultant's first name, last name, skill name, and certification which basically shows if the consultant is certified in their skill.  I am trying to create a script that will generate a table for each consultant with two columns (skills, and certification status) some consultants may have more than one skill.  I am thinking about the while loop syntax or dynamic sql but have no luck.  I have searched the web thoroughly with no luck.

Comment: Why on earth would you want a table for each consultant?

Comment: do you want to create a certification table and filter records based on certification and put them into new table? give some example of what you want to do.

Comment: This was a lab question at my college.  I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

You're probably best going about this a different way. Instead of creating tables for each record in another table, just create one second table that links to the first in a one-to-many relationship.

For example:

```
Consultant
----------
ConsultantID
Name


Skill
-----
SkillID
SkillName
F_ConsultantID
```

Comment: Foreign key relationship between two tables is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your proposed solution, I think you want a junction, or mapping table.

```
Consultant
    - ID
    - First_Name
    - Etc...

Skill
    - ID
    - Name

Consultant_Skill
    - Consultant_ID
    - Skill_ID
```

The `consultant_skill` table will allow you to have a many-to-many relationship between `consultant` and `skill`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that worked for me based on the lab question's parameters was:

```
USE Software

Declare @TableNameVar varchar(1000)
Declare @ConsultantIDVar int, @ConsultantIDMax int

Set @ConsultantIDVar = (Select MIN(ConsultantID) From Consultant)
Set @ConsultantIDMax = (Select MAX(ConsultantID) From Consultant)

While @ConsultantIDVar <= @ConsultantIDMax
Begin

   Set @TableNameVar = (Select (ConsultantFName + '_' + ConsultantLName)
                                From Consultant
                                Where ConsultantID = @ConsultantIDVar)

   Set @TableNameVar = 'Create Table '+ @TableNameVar + ' (SkillDescription varchar(40), Certification bit)'
   Exec (@TableNameVar)

   Set @ConsultantIDVar = @ConsultantIDVar + 1

End
```